# How to run pylint from py.test but not unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

We're using `py.test` to run Pylint under Jenkins using `py.test --pylint ...`. When we run it, `py.test` also picks up unittests that we have and is trying to run them.

We would like to split it so that we only run pylint in one run of `py.test`, and only run the unittests in another run of `py.test`. This way we can have separate stages in Jenkins for each.

The only way I know how to do that now is to `--ignore` the `tests` directory when running `py.test` for linting, but that's suboptimal because I'd like to lint the tests too of course.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to run `pylint` standalone, independently from `pytest`.

Nevertheless, it seems that `pytest-pylint` provides an option to skip unit tests:

> You can restrict your test run to only perform pylint checks and not any other tests by typing:
>
> py.test --pylint -m pylint

Source: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pylint/

Comment: I've posted a followup issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581453/restricting-a-py-test-to-only-run-pylint-and-not-unittests

Comment: As a side note, the reason we prefer to run linting under pytest is to get the nice `junit` style XML results which integrate more cleanly with Jenkins.