# Restricting py.test to only run pylint and not unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pylint

I'm trying to run `py.test` and execute only pylint, but not unittests.

The documentation on this page indicates you can do it:

https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pylint/

> You can restrict your test run to only perform pylint checks and not any other tests by typing:

```
  py.test --pylint -m pylint
```

But when I run that command exactly I still get errors from unittests that `py.test` found. The linting process seems to run as expected, then I get a bunch of errors in unittest files reported. This seems contrary to the documentation.

`py.test --version` shows that I'm using `0.14.0`:

```
$ py.test --version
This is pytest version 4.0.0, imported from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytest.py
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-pylint-0.14.0 at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytest_pylint.py
```

Comment: Are you getting linter errors about code style in unit tests or actual unit tests failures?

Comment: Good question, mostly module import errors, pythonpath issues in the unittest files that, while easy to solve, aren't supposed to be run at all. We want the lint errors only in this part of the Jenkins pipeline. We will define another part of the pipeline to run unittests properly.

Comment: One solution that might be proposed is to just lint and run unittests both, but the exclusions for linting and unittests will also be different, so it's not clean to run `py.test` once for both linting and unittests. Another soluiton would be to run `pylint` as its own process, not under `py.test`, but then we lose the `junit` results format that integrates into Jenkins more cleanly.

Comment: _"> mostly module import errors, pythonpath issues in the unittest files that, while easy to solve, aren't supposed to be run at all."_ - I think the explanation here is that `pytest` is trying to load unit test modules, but won't actually run them. `-m pylint` is a mark filter which means that only tests marked as "pylint" will have to be run. So `pytest` has to look through all the tests and inspect their marks. I would guess that solving the import/pythonpath issues would address the problem and `py.test --pylint -m pylint` would behave as expected.

Comment: You can run `pytest` with `-o norecursedirs=*` to avoid tests collection. `pytest --pylint -m pylint -o norecursedirs=*`. BTW don't use `py.test` anymore, it's deprecated and will be removed soon.

Comment: @Gediminas, that was the solution, you (or someone else in comments here) should post the answer. This worked, but you can't have import errors when linting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering on behalf of comments:

> Are you getting linter errors about code style in unit tests or actual
> unit tests failures? – Gediminas Feb 7 at 20:12
>
> Good question, mostly module import errors, pythonpath issues in the
> unittest files that, while easy to solve, aren't supposed to be run at
> all. We want the lint errors only in this part of the Jenkins
> pipeline. We will define another part of the pipeline to run unittests
> properly. – David Parks Feb 7 at 20:14

*"> mostly module import errors, pythonpath issues in the unittest files that, while easy to solve, aren't supposed to be run at all."* - I think the explanation here is that pytest is trying to load unit test modules, but won't actually run them. -m pylint is a mark filter which means that only tests marked as "pylint" will have to be run. So pytest has to look through all the tests and inspect their marks. I would guess that solving the import/pythonpath issues would address the problem and py.test --pylint -m pylint would behave as expected. – Gediminas Feb 7 at 20:47

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but consider using Prospector.

It is a wrapper around a few Python linting libraries, including pylint and it can generate xUnit reports out of the box.

See https://prospector.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html#output-format

Comment: Is this an `apt-get` install? The documentation doesn't mention installation at all. `apt-get` seems to want to include a whole lot of dependencies with this. I'm not sure I'll be able to sell the commitment it seems to require.

Comment: It should be installable just like any other regular Python package, e.g. using `pip install prospector`.